# Apache Ignite Failed to connect to any address from IP finder

Tags: java, spring, ignite, gridgain

I'm new to Apache Ignite, Here is what I'm trying to do I'm running GridGain in my local using default config xml (server side configuration). I guess we can say this is from server side configuration. Now I have my application which is from client which needs to listen to local running gridgain. My Goal is to I need to point to locally running cluster from my application

**I'm facing below issue:**

[org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi] (tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#59) Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2000 ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries): [/127.0.0.1:48500, /127.0.0.1:48501, /127.0.0.1:48502]
[stdout] (tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#59) [10:31:48] Failed to connect to any address from IP finder (will retry to join topology every 2000 ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to configure the frequency of retries): [/127.0.0.1:48500, /127.0.0.1:48501, /127.0.0.1:48502]

**server side configuration:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="communicationSpi">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
            <property name="localPort" value="48100"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**client side configuration:**

```
<bean name="igniteClientConfig" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
    <property name="discoverySpi" ref="tcpDiscoverySpi"/>
 
</bean>

<bean name="tcpDiscoverySpi" class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">

      <!-- Initial local port to listen to. -->
        <property name="localPort" value="48500"/>

        <!-- Changing local port range. This is an optional action. -->
        <property name="localPortRange" value="20"/>

        
    <property name="ipFinder" ref="tcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder"/>
</bean>

<bean name="tcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder" class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
    <property name="addresses" ref="IPaddresses"/>
</bean>



<util:list id="IPaddresses" value-type="java.lang.String">
     <value>127.0.0.1:48500</value>
    <value>127.0.0.1:48501</value>
    <value>127.0.0.1:48502</value>
</util:list>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the same discoverySpi and communicationSpi configs for all of your nodes (servers and clients)